# Why do the methods of a delegate couldn't be implemented in the main class firstly?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I cannot understand why the methods assigned to the delegate property of a class couldn't be implemented firstly on that class

IMO it would be easier to understand the code and the logic behind it but maybe I'm missing something

f.e.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView : UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell text"

    return cell
} }
```

wouldn't be easier if the methods present in the protocol (in this case the datasource and the UItableviewdelegate) were already into the UITableViewClass?